# Spark setup on Windows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to setup Spark on my Windows 10 PC. After executing the `spark-shell` command, I got the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':
  at rg.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark Installation on windows machine is not much difficult. We need to take care of some permissions and configurations during the installation. Please follow below link for step wise Spark and Scala installation and configuration on windows machine.

[Apache Spark Installation on windows10](https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/01/24/apache-spark-installation-on-windows-10/)